# Martingale diffusions falling in $\{-1,1\}$ at finite maturity

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

This is a continuation of [Characterization of martingale diffusions ending in $\{-1,1\}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407976/characterization-of-martingale-diffusions-ending-in-1-1)

$X=(X_t)_{0\le t\le T}$ is said to be a martingle diffusion if $X_0=0$, $X_T\in\{-1,1\}$ and

$$X_t=\int_0^t a(u,X_u)dW_u,\quad \forall t\in [0,T]$$

for some measurable function $a$. What kind of condition on $a$ may ensure the above properties of $X$?

Any answer, comments and references are highly appreciated.

PS : A simple construction is as follows: Take a Brownian motion, denoted by $(B_s)_{s\ge 0}$, in an arbitrary probability space. Set $\tau:=\inf\{s\ge 0: |B_s|\ge 1\}$ and $M= (M_t:=B_{\tau\wedge t})_{t\ge 0}$. Then $M$ is a martingale and $M_{\infty}\in \{-1,1\}$. Taking any (deterministic) time-change, e.g. $f:[0,T]\to [0,\infty]$ with

$$f(t):=\frac{t}{T-t},$$

$X=(X_t:=M_{f(t)})_{0\le t\le T}$ is a required martingale diffusion. Are we able to generalize this construction?

Comment: So $\{-1,1\}$ is to be understood to be the closed interval conventionally denoted $[-1,1]$?  Also, what kind of process is $W$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins Here $X_T\in\{-1,1\}$ means $\mathbb P[X_T= 1 \mbox{ or } X_T=-1]=1$. $W$ is a standard Brownian motion