# Does the entropy of a SDE with nondegenerate noise always increase?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, entropy

Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion, and let $X$ be the solution to the one dimensional SDE

$$dX_t = \sigma(t, X_t) \, dW_t$$

with initial condition $X_0 = x_0$ a.s. for some $x_0 \in \mathbb R$. We assume $\sigma$ is Lipschitz continuous and uniformly bounded away from $0$.

Suppose that $X_t$ admits a density $f_t$ for all $t > 0$.

**Question:** Is it true that we have the entropy inequality

$$\mathbb E[-\log f_t (X_t)] > \mathbb E[-\log f_s (X_s)]$$

for all $t > s$ in $\mathbb R_+$?

Comment: Since this is a supermartingale type question, one good start is computing the Ito for that log expression to see exactly what integrals are involved.

Comment: Right i guess assuming smoothness of the densities this is a pretty good idea!

Comment: yes and I was thinking that then maybe the Fokker-Plank equation for densities might then come into use to simplify that Ito expression.

Comment: another thought, I had was the situation with super-harmonic functions and supermartingales. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304050/superharmonic-function-and-super-martingale. The log function is harmonic and then the density satisfies the elliptic equation given by Fokker-Plank. So then I was thinking to then possibly use the mean value property for elliptic equations to get that supermartingale property.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, they sound promising indeed. Will definitely give this a go and let you know how it goes.

Comment: you know that this is known for markov chains, I think it is an exercise in karlin & taylor.  It seems to me the same argument works here, i.e., that the markov property is crucial,  but I don't know what technicalities may arise.

Comment: @mike By Markov chains, you mean in discrete time? A reference would be great!

Comment: @mike : Markov chains? What about a chain on $\{1,2\}$, with $2$ absorbing and $1$ not absorbing? Then the entropy will be $0$ after one step, but not necessarily intially.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I suppose the analogue of non degenerate noise in this case would be nonzero probability of reaching any state from any other state.

Comment: An elementary idea would be to compare with the trivial case $dY_t = c \, dW_t$, where $c > 0$ is the uniform bound on $\sigma$. The inequality clearly holds in this case, but exactly how to compare with this is unclear. The result [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438492/blow-up-limits-for-sde) may be helpful somehow.

Comment: No, you are right, I bungled that, fwiw, I had in mind problem 3.14 in Karlin and Taylor vol 1

Comment: @NateRiver : Sorry, I don't understand your "@IosifPinelis" comment. Can you rephrase it, without using terms like "this"?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis Ah, I was trying to say that the analogue of the condition “$\sigma$ bounded away from $0$” in the case of a countable state Markov chain is that the transition probabilities are all uniformly bounded away from $0$. It’s plausible that the entropy inequality holds for the Markov chain under these conditions.

Comment: @NateRiver : I don't think so. If you look back at my two-state Markov chain example and modify it slightly by making $2$ only 'almost absorbing" (with some small enough transition probability $p_{21}$), then, by continuity, the entropy can still decrease after one step.

Comment: Hmm you are right…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\pa}{\partial}$The answer is no. The idea is to get a diffusion version of my [two-state Markov chain example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447513/does-the-entropy-of-a-sde-with-nondegenerate-noise-always-increase#comment1156881_447513).

Indeed, for $t\in(0,\infty)$ and real $x$, let
\begin{equation*}
    b(x,t):=e^{(t+1)^2 x^2/(2 t)}+\frac{1-t}{2 (t+1)^3}\ge1+\frac{1-t}{2 (t+1)^3}\ge\frac{53}{54}>\frac12, \tag{-1}\label{-1}
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
    \si(x,t):=\sqrt{2b(x,t)}\ge1. 
\end{equation*}
Moreover, letting
\begin{equation*}
    f_t(x):=f(x,t):=g_{0,t/(t+1)^2}(x), \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation*}
where $g_{a,s^2}$ is the density of the normal distribution with mean $a$ and variance $s^2$, we see that $f$ is a solution of the [Fokker–Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation)
\begin{equation*}
\pa_t f(x,t)=\pa_x^2(b(x,t)f(x,t)). \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
So, $f_t$ is the density of $X_t$ given the SDE
\begin{equation*}
    dX_t=\si(X_t,t)\,dW_t
\end{equation*}
with the initial condition $X_0=0$ (since the $EX_t^2=t/(t+1)^2\to0$ as $t\downarrow0$).

However, the entropy
\begin{equation*}
    \int_\R f_t\ln\frac1{f_t}=\frac{1}{2} (\ln (2 \pi  t)-2 \ln (t+1)+1)
\end{equation*}
decreases in $t\ge1$. $\quad\Box$

---

*Discussion:* The example above may seem counterintuitive. Indeed, if $\si(x,t)$ does not depend on $x$, then $X_t$ will be normally distributed for each $t$ with variance increasing with $t$, and hence with the entropy increasing with $t$.

In our example, $X_t$ is still normally distributed for each $t$, but the variance $t/(t+1)^2$ of $X_t$ is decreasing in $t\ge1$. As noted in the last paragraph, this can only happen if the diffusion coefficient $b(x,t)=\si(x,t)^2/2$ depends on $x$.

We wanted the variance of $X_t$ to be decreasing in (say) $t\ge1$. It may then seem counterintuitive that the diffusion coefficient $b(x,t)$ in our example increases very fast in $|x|$, especially for large $t$. The Fokker–Planck equation \eqref{1} may help shed some light here. Indeed, suppose first that we are looking for a solution $f$ of \eqref{1} stationary in $t$. Then \eqref{1} implies that $b(x,t)f(x,t)$ is affine in $x$. If $b(x,t)$ and $f(x,t)$ are also even in $x$, then $b(x,t)f(x,t)$ must be constant in $x$. So then, if $f_t$ is a normal density and hence $f(x,t)$ is decreasing fast in $|x|$, then $b(x,t)$ must be increasing fast in $|x|$. If now the variance of $X_t$ is decreasing somewhat slowly for large $t$, then we may expect that $b(x,t)$ must still be increasing fast in $|x|$, as is the case in our example.

Actually, the way $b(x,t)$ was found in our example is as follows. We **want** \eqref{0} to hold. With $f$ so prescribed, for each $t$ equation \eqref{1} becomes a simple ODE (with respect to $x$) for the function $b_t:=b(\cdot,t)$. Thus we get the expression for $b(x,t)$ in \eqref{-1}, with a certain choice of the integration constants.

Comment: Thank you for the intuitive discussion at the end! Makes it much easier to digest.

Comment: @NateRiver : You are very welcome. Thank you for your appreciation of the discussion.