# Strong blow up limits for SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

*Note: This is a strengthening of the following [result](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438492/blow-up-limits-for-sde), motivated by the need for strong convergence in applications.*

Let $W$ be a one dimensional standard Brownian motion, and let $X$ be the solution to the SDE

$$dX_t = \sigma(X_t) \, dW_t \, , \, X_0 = 0$$

with $\sigma: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ Lipschitz continuous.

For each $c > 0$, define the process $Y^c$ on $[0, 1]$ by

$$X^c_t := c^{-1/2} X_{ct}.$$

Similarly define

$$W^c_t := c^{-1/2} \, W_{ct}.$$

**Question:** Is it true that as $c \to 0^+$, we have

$$\mathbb E[\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} |X^c_t - \sigma(0) W^c_t|] \to 0?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Since $(X_{t}^{c})_{t\geq{0}}$ and $(W_{t}^{c})_{t\geq{0}}$ are both martingales for fixed $c$, applying Cauchy- Schwarz and then Doob's inequality tells us that:
$$
\mathbb{E}(\sup_{0\leq{t}\leq{1}}|X_{t}^{c}-\sigma(0)W_{t}^{c}|)\leq{\big(\mathbb{E}(\sup_{0\leq{t}\leq{1}}|X_{t}^{c}-\sigma(0)W_{t}^{c}|^{2})\big)^{1/2}}\leq{\sqrt{2}\big(\mathbb{E}|X_{1}^{c}-\sigma(0)W_{1}^{c}|^{2}\big)^{1/2}}
$$
By our SDE for $(X_{t})_{t\geq{0}}$ we have that:
$$
X_{1}^{c}=c^{1/2}X_{c}=c^{1/2}\int_{0}^{c}\sigma(X_{u})dW_{u}=c^{1/2}\int_{0}^{1}\sigma(X_{cr})dW_{cr}=\int_{0}^{1}\sigma(X_{cr})dW^{c}_{r}
$$
Since $(W^{c}_{t})_{t\geq{0}}$ is a standard Brownian motion for any $c>0$, by the Ito isometry:
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_{1}^{c}-\sigma(0)W_{1}^{c})^{2}=\mathbb{E}\Big(\int_{0}^{1}(\sigma(X_{cr})-\sigma(0))dW^{c}_{r}\Big)^{2}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{E}(\sigma(X_{cr})-\sigma(0))^{2}dr
$$
If $L>0$ is the Lipschitz constant of $\sigma$, we have that:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{E}(\sigma(X_{cr})-\sigma(0))^{2}dr\leq{L^{2}\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{E}X_{cr}^{2}dr}\leq{L^{2}\sup_{0\leq{r}\leq{1}}\mathbb{E}X_{cr}^{2}}\leq{2L^{2}\mathbb{E}X_{c}^{2}}
$$
The last inequality follows by Doob's inequality, since $(X_{t})_{t\geq{0}}$ is a martingale. Finally, recall that by the Gronwall- type argument in [1](https://mathoverflow.net/a/438499/80052) we have that:
$$
\mathbb{E}X_{c}^{2}\leq{\frac{\sigma^{2}(0)}{L^{2}}\big(e^{2L^{2}c}-1\big)}
$$
Putting all this together, we have that:
$$
\mathbb{E}(\sup_{0\leq{t}\leq{1}}|X_{t}^{c}-\sigma(0)W_{t}^{c}|)\leq{2|\sigma(0)|\sqrt{e^{2L^{2}c}-1}}\rightarrow{0} \hspace{10pt}\text{as}\hspace{10pt}c\rightarrow{0}
$$

Comment: Ah, nice trick with the Cauchy Schwartz! That and Doobs inequality (together with your earlier work) yields the answer quite handily.